# Forcing a file download through HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, href

I am trying to trigger a download by providing filename but instead of downloading it's opening in the tab. Following is my code which I am using. Also I am using Chrome Browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
   <body> 
      <p> 
         <a href="someFile.png" download="ID"> 
         <button type="button">Download</button> 
         </a> 
   </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `button` nesteded into `a` is invalid HTML to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<a href="someFile.png" download>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
</a>
```

I think you have something wrong with your browser, try to change the browser.

Also, I’d suggest you to go the setting of Chrome and scroll down to advanced settings. In the section of Downloads, click `clear` your Auto Open options. And, turn on `Ask where to save each file before downloading`.

Comment: Even this is not working. I tried with edge also but it's giving me option to open and cancel, not to save.

Comment: @Deepesh Sharma I would suggest you to go the setting of Chrome and scroll down to advanced settings. In the section of Downloads, click `clear` your Auto Open options. And, turn on `Ask where to save each file before downloading`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a anchor element first, then you can download your file. Follow the code snippet.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'file_path';  // file path for the blob object.
a.download = 'file_name.png';  // set file name
a.click();
```

Comment: Opening in new tab with this

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has deprecated cross-origin download see [chrome-65-deprecations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download), you need to put your image on same origin, then it will work.

Here is the working javascript example but your image should be on same origin.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#download_button');

btn.onclick = function() {
  const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.setAttribute("href", "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png");
      link.setAttribute("download", "airplane.png");
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
   <body> 
      <p> 
         <button id="download_button" type="button">Download</button>
      </p>
   </body> 
</html>
```